# How do mystic adepts gain power points in Shadowrun 5?

Tags: shadowrun, shadowrun-sr5

I recently bought the SR5 PDF and am really liking many of the changes. Especially that mystic adepts are not as underpowered as in previous editions. However how they gain power points *during character advancement* seems to be unclear, as this is only described for adepts (without mention of mystic adepts).

During character creation, mystic adepts can buy power points for 5 karma each, up to their magic attribute. Nothing similar is mentioned in the character advancement rules, only that adepts gain one power point for each point of magic they gain (or from gaining a power point on initiation instead of learning a metamagic technique).

Do mystic adepts also gain a power point for each point of magic without spending additional karma? Can they spend extra karma for magic points for which they did not buy power points during character creation? And last but not least, can they also gain extra power points instead of learning new metamagic techniques?

Comment: As far as I know the 2 Karma/Power Point will be Errata'ed to 5 (together with a few other minor changes).

Comment: @JoachimSauer the errata is out, your are right. http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/2014/02/shadowrun-fifth-edition-errata-now-available/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The new [errata](http://www.shadowruntabletop.com/2014/02/shadowrun-fifth-edition-errata-now-available/) answers the question clearly:

> Change to following sentence: “You get a free Power Point whenever you
>   increase your Magic attribute, and you can gain a Power Point through
>   Initiation (p. 324) instead of gaining a metamagic.” To: “If you’re an
>   adept, you get a free Power Point whenever you increase your Magic
>   attribute (though this doesn’t apply to mystic adepts, and you can
>   gain a Power Point through Initiation (p. 324) instead of gaining a
>   metamagic.”

Therefore, further power points do not require spending of karma, but do require to forfeit a metamagic when initiating, and can *only* be acquired by initiation.

Answer (score 6):

First, this is a good question, and after checking all over the place, it never *clearly* says how it works for mystic adepts. Therefore, this will be *my* reading of the rules, to the best of my ability.

The most important passage is the following:

> At character creation, adepts receive Power Points equal to their
>   Magic attribute, while mystic adepts have to buy Power Points with
>   Karma. ***Subsequently***, Power Points can come in two ways. You get a free
>   Power Point whenever you increase your Magic attribute, and you can
>   gain a Power Point through Initiation (p. 324) instead of gaining a
>   metamagic. - p. 279 SR5

As I understand it, everything after "Subsequently" applies to both adepts and mystic adepts. This would mean that yes, they gain a Power Point for each new Magic point without spending karma, and yes, they can get extra Power Points instead of learning new metamagic techniques.

As for spending extra karma for magic points for which they did not buy power points during character creation, I couldn't find anything saying you could... nor anything saying you could not.

Comment: That is my initial reading as well which seems quite broken, since mystics adepts would gain power points at the same rate as adepts... while becoming more powerful at spellcasting at the same rate as mages. With no extra karma spent.

Comment: @Joe But 10-12 Karma behind, without astral projection, needing more skills that normal adepts, and having to choose between adept metamagics and mage metamagics. With this reading, it's on the thin line between "broken" and "decent alternative to mages". I'll update once the errata is out.

Comment: 10-12 karma (actually 20-24 when viewed as qualities) tends to become fairly irrelevant over the course of a long campaign. Currently looks as if it will rise to 5 karma per point in the errata.

Comment: Accepted as this seems to be the RAW

Comment: @Joe I will update anyway as far as I find a definite answer to "Can they spend extra karma for magic points for which they did not buy power points during character creation?", which is quite important in my opinion

Comment: There's some errata out for upcoming conventions that's saying Mystic Adepts do not get free Power Points when raising their magic rating.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12034805/SRM5%20Hot%20Patch%20Errata%20v1.0.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You gain a power point every time you increase your magic attribute

> You get a free Power Point whenever you increase
>   your Magic attribute, and you can gain a Power
>   Point through Initiation (p. 324) instead of gaining a
>   metamagic. - p. 279 SR5 Core

You can also gain power points as part of initiation

> Power Point (Adepts Only): If you’re an adept, you
>   gain a Power Point instead of a metamagic. You can take
>   this as many times as you like. - p. 326 SR5 Core

Comment: The second one is actually part of what makes it unclear, because in the context of character creation "Adept" and "Mystic Adept" are two very different things. Therefore "Adepts only" seems to indicate that it applies only to regular adepts, not to mystic adepts.

Comment: Mystic adepts are mentioned in the same context as adepts in regards for increasing their power points using Initiation. Therefor they are adepts when it comes to adepts only. Adepts and mystic adepts are "adepts only" and magician and aspected magicians are "magicians".