# With street grimoire out are there more ways by which mystic adepts can gain power points?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5, character-advancement

As mentioned here: [How do mystic adepts gain power points in Shadowrun 5?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27290/how-do-mystic-adepts-gain-power-points-in-shadowrun-5) mystic adepts can gain power points at character creation. Later on they can only gain them by not choosing a metamagic ability during an initiation.

With street grimoire out now are there additional ways / what are the ways now by which (mystic) adepts can gain power points after character creation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do mystic adepts gain power points in Shadowrun 5?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27290/how-do-mystic-adepts-gain-power-points-in-shadowrun-5)

Comment: I just saw that there is a question that is essentially the same as mine (the question itself. The answer here though has a few more details to it): http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/27290/how-do-mystic-adepts-gain-power-points-in-shadowrun-5?rq=1

Comment: Updated the question so that it shouldn't be a complete duplicate any longer (saw that the other question was out before street grimoire came out so focused on that in the edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *power points* section on p. 278f confirms your assumption. Of course that means mystic adepts either buy the power points at character creation or loose the opportunity to do so permanently. However there are a few ways of gaining new adept powers after character creation that do not require buying new power points:

- qi foci (core rules p. 319) can give you additional powers (or increase existing ones), but you'll risk focus addiction if you go overboard
- getting a *mentor spirit* (and choosing the adept power(s) as mystic adept) (core rules p. 320ff)
- blood magic adepts can temporaryly steal powers from other adepts with the *power bleed* meta magic (Streetgrimoire p. 90). But the drawback is that most people will try to kill them, if they recognize they're a blood mage, or at least organize a manhunt...

  And the GM *may* not allow it - or just die laughing if you try to convince him/her to allow it (they do this in the missions faq - seriously)
- Following a way (Streetgrimoire p. 176ff) can reduce the cost of adept powers, which allows you to buy new ones; but the number of points you can reduce the costs sum up to at most `MAG/4`
- The *infusion* meta magic (Streetgrimoire p. 156) allows you to temporaryly increase the power of one of your adept powers, but that has some nasty side effects
- the *qi sculpt* meta magic (Streetgrimoire p. 156) allows you to "transfer power points" between 2 of your powers. (Also nasty side effects)

Comment: The laughing part: With a few players it can turn into quite a whailing part on behalf of the gm......I know a few players who could turn such powers into something that can kill the last nerve of the gm^^